# Layout folder for nexus 7 not being used

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've spent a few hours on this now. I have defined a layout for my app in three separate folders:

```
layout-sw240dp
layout-sw354dp
layout-sw600dp
```

Using Android Studio the app looks fine in design view on the Nexus 1, 4 and 7. I have tested using a Samsung Galaxy S2 and S3, HTC One S, Galaxy Note II and a Nexus, and the requisite layouts are served to the requisite devices. Except the Nexus 7.

The N7 seems to be using the layout-sw240dp folder. I have no idea whats going on here as the preview shows the correct layout. There seems to be conflicting advice about the correct way to use these layout folders (including on the Android dev site) and some definitive and authoritative response would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify what part of the official docs that are conflicting?
Looking at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html it seems to me that the Nexus 7 should be using the sw240dp layout folder.

Comment: @mclhrn I don't think that it should be using sw240dp folder, since nexus 7 smallest width is 600. Could you check if the layout you defined is in the sw600dp folder? do you have dimens defined in the correct folder?

Comment: I'm using the sw240dp folder to target low ppi 4.3" screens, which works fine. The docs say _"you should instead use the sw<N>dp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources"_ .That's what I've done here. I am also providing the sw600dp for the N7 but that is being ignored.

Comment: I've just tried it without the sw240dp and it seems that the layout being used by the N7 is in fact the main layout file in 'res/layout/activity_main' . It seems the N7 is ignoring the custom layout directories altogether.